# How to implement facebook like timestamp difference function

Tags: php, timestamp

I am designing a facebook like timestamp difference function using php as shown below :

```
function time_parser($time)
    {

        if(!is_numeric($time))
        {
            $time = strtotime($time);
            if(!is_numeric($time))
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
        $difference = time() - $time;
        $periods = array("sec","min","hour","day","week","month","year");
        $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

        if($difference > 0)
        {
            $ending = "ago";
        }
        else
        {
            $difference = -$difference;
            $ending = "to go";
        }
        for($j=0; $difference>=$lengths[$j] && $j<7;$j++)
        {
            $difference /= $lengths[$j];
        }
        $difference = round($difference);
        if($difference!=1)
        {
            $periods[$j].="s";
        }
                    $text = "$difference $periods[$j] $ending";
        return $text;
    }
```

Now the problem is , it gives results in hours for a time which is a minute ago . What is wrong ? Does it depend on the timezone settings of my pc?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+time+ago

Comment: @deceze...thanks  for the search thread ...allthough what I was doing , was a stupid mistake , instead of converting $time to a **time** object , I was simply performing the difference...lol..

Comment: javascript times/dates depend on the system clock of the *client* pc.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to go with JavaScript than PHP for the time conversion.

http://tinywall.info/2011/10/09/facebook-like-friendly-time-with-gmt-and-utc-in-web-application-with-php-javascript/